# Converting altitude in feet to pixels on a mercator map image

Tags: coordinate-system

I know the question might seem farfetched given that the map is 2d. But I essentially want to project items-aircraft-above the map and I would like their altitude to be vaguely 'realistic' in terms of map size etc. The whole thing is 3D so it is possible to see the altitude.

I have the altitude in feet.

Is it simply a case of world diameter / image width = number of feet represented in a pixel.
altitude in feet / number of feet represented in a pixe

I get the feeling that would be too simple.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question because--as you write--you are talking about depicting "altitude" on a 2D map but you then go on to say the "whole thing is 3D"; this sounds inherently contradictory, but that's probably because the question is vague. Could you describe your data and tell us what the resulting image ought to look like?

Comment: Yes, sorry the question is confusing. The visualisation is 3d, within it there is a 2D map of the world on the XZ axis. Essentially a floating rectangle. the altitude is plotted on the Y axis, if that makes sense? so there is some objects floating above this map, I would like their position above it to be reflective of their real altitude. I put the equation the wrong way round in my post, should be imagewidth/world diameter. I think.